# I'm trying to implement a Flutter application that displays a list of items and allows the user to add a new item via an input field and an dd button

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to implement a Flutter application that displays a list of items and allows the user to add a new item via an input field and an add button. But I'm having trouble adding the new item to the list.

You have successfully designed the UI and bound the input field and add button to empty functions so far. But when I add the new item and press the button, the item is not added to the list. I'm not sure what the correct procedure is to add the new item to the list and update the interface properly. Please help direct me to the correct procedure to add the item to the list and update the interface properly. Thanks!

Comment: Show us your code

Comment: I think the issue is that your screen is not being refreshed properly, you might have not used "setstate" or any state-management. Can't comment more Without watching the code.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, you have created a list where you are adding your items when you click on "Add" button.

**Solution 1**
Use Stateful widget to render the list. Here, you need to call setState on UI after you add the item to the list.

**Solution 2**
If you don't want to use Stateful widget. You can us `ValueListenableBuilder`

Example -

```
ValueNotifier<List<String>> list = [];

// Add button click
void onClick() {
  list.add("new value");
}

ValueListenableBuilder(
      valueListenable: list,
      builder: (_, items, ___) => ListView.builder(
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        itemCount: items.length,
        itemBuilder: (_, index) => Text(items[index]),
      ),
    );
```